# New laptop boots slowly when low battery

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

I have a new laptop (2 months old) with the following specs

- AMD Ryzen 4700
- AMD Radeon Graphics
- 8GB RAM 1200GHz
- 500GB storage SSD

and, most of the time, it boots very quickly (i'd say a few seconds) and runs perfectly. Sometimes, however, when it boots with low battery (maybe <20%) it does that incredibly slowly, and it also runs slowly when it's on. After a few restarts however it works fine.

Why is that?

Ps. It runs with Windows 10

Comment: Your computer most likely runs in powersafe because battery is low in order to get the most out of your battery. Given it does this at boot suggests this is something set from UEFI.

Comment: what if it does that even when I reboot it plugged it? (still low battery) I once noticed it stopped being slow at >30%

Comment: Again, its very likely that this is a powersaving feature. If the adapter is not capable of sustained load because the charger is say... 120Watt, and a sustained load does 130Watt, you would get to the point where you could not use the laptop and charge if the battery is too low. Gaming laptops will have this. So its likely, as a failsafe, powersaving will clock things down to go under the 120Watt (in this example) so it will charge regardless the load. Keep in mind, boot will require lots of power.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: For power-hungry applications, Windows 10 has an option to max out your CPU. It’s not the ideal way to run your computer (it produces extra heat), but it should cover your needs for brief periods of high demand usage. You can try these detailed step for test: 1. Right click the Start menu and select Control Panel. 2. Click Hardware and Sound. 3. Select Power Options. 4. Find Processor power management and open the menu for Minimum processor state. 5. Change the setting for on battery to 100%. 6. Change the setting for plugged in to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer most likely runs in powersafe because battery is low in order to get the most out of your battery. Given it does this at boot suggests this is something set from UEFI

If the adapter is not capable of sustained load because the charger is say... 120Watt, and a sustained load does 130Watt, you would get to the point where you could not use the laptop and charge if the battery is too low.

Gaming laptops will have this. So its likely, as a failsafe, powersaving will clock things down to go under the 120Watt (in this example) so it will charge regardless the load.

Keep in mind, booting a pc will require lots of power, even after you see your desktop, it still boots for a while, but you gain the ability to do things.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to fix this? The adapter is certainly capable of prodiving enough power, as it usually charges very fast even during heavy load activities

Comment: Go into the UEFI bios and look for a powersaving setting.

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops intentionally slow down when they are running on battery in order to conserve power. The processor (CPU) in the laptop switches to a slower speed, and processors use less power when running slower, so the battery should last longer.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to fix this? The adapter is certainly capable of prodiving enough power, as it usually charges very fast even during heavy load activities